# Can I change storage file location in RED5 server?

Tags: red5

I have setup `Red5 server` on my machine. It is working fine, **only my problem is that I can not set up custom path for created new file.**

I have googled on many sites, but there is no any solution. If any have any idea, please share.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of using custom paths for recording and playback here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/Customize-Stream-Path